# Windows phone 8.1 crop Image

Tags: image, image-processing, windows-phone-8.1, crop

I am new  to Windows Phone programming.  I'm trying to  create a Face detection application. My problem is that I am not able to correctly crop the image by rectangle which detecs the face.

Here are original and cropped image: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=3F56C0D8DEC03C5B%21109

```
foreach (var r in faces)
{                                
    System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle toAdd = new System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle();                    
    TranslateTransform loc = new TranslateTransform();

    loc.X = r.X * _downsampleFactor / (double)w * cnvsFaceRegions.ActualWidth;
    loc.Y = r.Y * _downsampleFactor / (double)w * cnvsFaceRegions.ActualHeight;                     
    toAdd.RenderTransform = loc;
    toAdd.Width = r.Width * _downsampleFactor+50;
    toAdd.Height = r.Height * _downsampleFactor+50;
    toAdd.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);

    cnvsFaceRegions.Children.Add(toAdd);
    widthRectangle = toAdd.Width;
    heightRectangle = toAdd.Height;
    point1 = loc.X ;
    point2 = loc.Y ;

}
```

And here I crop the image:

```
 private  void  SaveScreenShots()            
 {             
   WriteableBitmap bmp = new WriteableBitmap((int)this.ActualWidth, (int)this.ActualHeight);           
   WriteableBitmap bmp2= CropImage(bmp,(int)point1, (int)point2, (int)widthRectangle, (int)heightRectangle);             
   bmp2.Render(this, null);
   byte[] bb = EncodeToJpeg(bmp2);
   bmp2.Invalidate();

   MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream();
   bmp2.SaveJpeg(mem, bmp2.PixelWidth, bmp2.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
   mem.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);

   if (mem != null)
   {

       MediaLibrary library = new MediaLibrary();
       try
       {

           pic = library.SavePicture("Mask_" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), mem);
           MaskPath = pic.GetPath();
           Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
           {
               MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("", "Saved successfully", MessageBoxButton.OK);

           });

       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           MessageBox.Show("Unable to save the photo." + ex);

       }
   }     
        cameraViewer.NewCameraFrame += NewCameraFrame;
    }
```

Crop function:

```
 private static WriteableBitmap CropImage(WriteableBitmap source, int xOffset, int yOffset, int width, int height)
     {

         var sourceWidth = source.PixelWidth;
         var result = new WriteableBitmap(width, height);
         for (var x = 0; x <= height - 1; x++)
         {
             var sourceIndex = xOffset + (yOffset + x) * sourceWidth;
             var destinationIndex = x * width;
             Array.Copy(source.Pixels, sourceIndex, result.Pixels, destinationIndex, width);
         }
         return result;

     }
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: It seems to be a mismatch between the size you think the picture has and its real size. In the full screen screenshot the rectangle has 300x300 but the cropped image has 362x362.

I suggest you compare the `WriteableBitmap source` width/height with the width/height you are expecting it to have.

Comment: I made another photo and upload it. The cropped image has the same size (362x362) as the Rectangle in original photo.

Comment: The rectangle in the screenshot is 300x300, not 362x362. That is why I'm saying you should check if all the objects you are accessing/creating have the same size.

Comment: Yes , but it was previous image. I made another one and uploaded here as 1.jpg and 2.jpg 
https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=3F56C0D8DEC03C5B%21109

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but the problem here seems to be the offset. It is cropping with the correct width and height, but instead of starting in the xOffset and yOffset valuse, it is starting in the 0,0 coordinate. Can you debug your code and tell me the values of the xOffset and yOffset when you reach the CropImage function?

Comment: Yes the width and height are correct. I debuged my code and xOffset=63, yOffset=140 for picture which I now uploaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `crop` implementation is not correct.

```
var sourceIndex = xOffset + (yOffset + x) * sourceWidth;
```

You want an offset that mirrors the equation for a `Line`

```
y = mx + b;    // where y is your offset
               // m is your vertical position
               // x is your width
               // b is your starting horizontal position
```

So you basically copy a horizontal section of the image and copy those pixels to the buffer, repeat until you have enough sections.

Full implementation:

```C#
private WriteableBitmap CropImage(WriteableBitmap source, int x, int y, int width, int height)
{
    // range check
    if (x < 0 || y < 0 || width <= 0 || height <= 0)
        return null;

    // create the bitmap
    WriteableBitmap dest = new WriteableBitmap(width, height);

    // calculate the starting offset
    int offset = (y * source.PixelWidth) + x;

    // copy each row of pixels from the starting y location to (y + height) with the width of width
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        Array.Copy(source.Pixels, offset, dest.Pixels, i * width, width);
        offset += source.PixelWidth;
    }

    // return the crop image
    return dest;
}
```

---

Additional References

[How to Crop an Image using the WriteableBitmap class](http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2012/12/how-to-crop-image-using-writeablebitmap.html)

Comment: I tried to use these function , but still have the same problem. The crop function does not work correctly and I still see only part of Rectangle.

Comment: @Fačko I assure you the crop image function above is correct.  I'm guessing your program flow is now the problem.  For instance, why do you crop the image and then render to it?  It should be render to the image first, then crop.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was in my program flow. It almost works perfect when I first render and after that crop image. But I have to add 27 to yOffset parameters to function to crop image correctly and do not know why.

WriteableBitmap bmp2 = CropImage2(bmp, (int)point1, (int)point2+27, (int)widthRectangle, (int)heightRectangle);